# Generalized solution for applying flex rules to multiple Angular 4 components

Tags: angular, css, flexbox, angular-router

I have multiple tabs and sub-tabs in my application and each of those tabs and subtabs is a component. They need to grow and shrink as available space to them grows or shrinks.

One key step to achieve that flexible layout is setting following main CSS rule in my app level CSS file for all of the components which are children of the main app:

```
/* app-level.component.css */
:host ::ng-deep tab1,
:host ::ng-deep tab2,
:host ::ng-deep tab1-subtab1,
:host ::ng-deep tab1-subtab2 {
{
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
```

where `tab1`, `tab2`, `tab1-subtab1`, `tab1-subtab2` are **selectors** e.g. for tab1:

```
/* tab1.component.ts */
@Component({
  selector: 'tab1',
  templateUrl: './tab1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tab1.component.css']
})
```

Above mentioned in just an example. Consider an application with 10 tabs and many subtabs. In that case, first problem is that I will have to manually write down selectors for all those tabs in the app-level.component.css.

Another problem is that in near future some new developer may introduce a new tab but his tab's content will not grow-shrink as expected because he/she doesn't even know that they have to add their component's selector to the app-level-component.css.

Is there a more generalized and recommended way to approach this problem with Angular 4 such that:

1. I don't have to pollute app.component.css with all those `selectors`
2. Each future tab automatically have the style applied to it already.

I suppose **Decorators** may be the right way to go about this in order to at-least solve #1. For #2, it seems like the developer of new tab will have to at-least apply that decorator to his component so there is some work he/she will have to do but its not as bad as figuring out addition of the required rule to app-component.css. Which kind of decorator should I look into?

**Note:**
tab1, tab2, tab1-subtab1, tab1-subtab2 are not classes. They are components generated by Angular Router.

Comment: To avoid using app.css, put the tab css in it's own file to be imported into each component's styleUrls array.

Comment: I was doing that earlier but problem with that is I have to copy that rule to each component's css file. Looking for a generalized solution so I have to specify the rule in one place but it should reflect for all components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two main constraints were mentioned in the answer's description:

1. app.component.css should not be polluted with selectors for each component
2. Each future tab automatically have the style applied to it already.

Following app level generalized CSS rule takes care of both. As those components were generated by Angular Router. We find `router-outlet` and apply the CSS to its immediate sibling (by using the adjacent sibling combinator) which are our components for tabs and subtabs.

```
:host ::ng-deep router-outlet + * { 
   display: flex; 
   flex: 1 1 auto; 
   flex-flow: column nowrap 
}
```

New developers will not have to do anything extra for their new tabs/subtabs.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use the attribute selector [`[attr=value]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), which have a few expressions so one can target i.e. classes starting with a certain word or containing one.

```
[attr^=value]
```

Represents an element with an attribute name of attr whose value is prefixed (preceded) by value.

```
[attr*=value]
```

Represents an element with an attribute name of attr whose value contains at least one occurrence of value within the string.

And could be use like this

```
:host ::ng-deep [class^='tab']          /*  start with 'tab'  */
{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

:host ::ng-deep [class*='-subtab']      /*  contain '-subtab'  */
{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
```

---

Attribute selectors can be used with what you called **Decorators** as well, i.e.

```
:host ::ng-deep [flexcontainer]   /*  has the attribute `flexcontainer`  */
{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

:host ::ng-deep [flexitem]        /*  has the attribute `flexitem`  */
{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Comment: Good idea but I have no control over names of tabs. Someone may name their selector as "trump".

Comment: @baltoro If you can't control their name then use the global selector `:host ::ng-deep * { ... }`

Comment: That will select all other components beside the tabs. No? I guess I should use a global selector but make it compulsory for developers to have some metadata like the string "tab" in their selectors.

Comment: @baltoro Yes it will...added a second part to my answer that cover element decorators

Comment: @baltoro The absolute best would to either use a specific word in the class, or a specific decorator, as using the global selector like this I wouldn't recommend

Comment: flexcontainer and flexitem will need to be 'defined' only in app level component, right? And used by all of this children by merely adding the property to their html.

Comment: @baltoro Yes, as CSS, and then simply add them to the element as an attribute like this `<div class="tab1" flexcontainer></div>`

Comment: Those tabs are generated by Angular router. Not by doing something like `<div class="tab1"><div>. Its more like <tab1></tab1> which is generated by Angular router. You may see in my question that tab1, tab2 etc. are not classes.

Comment: @baltoro And how does the _decorator_ get applied and look like on the rendered element?

Comment: That's the part I did not know; still learning about Decorators. Anyway, I solved the issue using router-outlet's adjacent tag which corresponds to my tabs and sub tab (see my answer).

Comment: @baltoro That's great, upvoted ... and if you want to also choose that as the accepted answer, please do :)